# SDRAM connection to Nios2 on DE10-Nano

Tags: fpga, quartus, nios-ii

I am pretty new to fpga world and trying to do an image processing application using Nios2 processor on a DE10-Nano dev board for university and I'm using the platform designer from Quartus. The goal is to use the sdram on the board but since I'm using VGA for the output we need different PLLs for the SDRAM controller and the VGA controller blocks. I am dumbfounded as how to connect everything together and to the sysclock.

I have tried using the university program IP blocks but the problem is I don't know how to connect all these different PLL blocks.

Comment: `using VGA for the output` If I didn't remember clocks there, I could read up on it: Tell everyone about the input! Did you evaluate `sysclock` locked to the SDRAM clock? How many interdependent clocks are you planning on?